# Need help in Sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint development and i have task in hand to do. I need to add few lines of code for the following logic.

1. Need to check if previous title and new title of task items are same.
2. If Not, then query the Task list
3. Find all the items which contain the previous title
4. Update their titles.

Here is my Pseudocode:

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
try {
        this.DisableEventFiring();
        //Need to write my logic here

        base.ItemUpdating(properties);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    finally {
        this.EnableEventFiring();
    }
}
```

Can somebody guide me how to write the code for the above mentioned logic? If you have any sample code's with similar logic, please share it. It will be helpful for me.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

This code might help you out. Maybe you need to adapt it for your needs, but the properties you need to access are the same.

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
  //this will get your title before updating
  var oldName = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();

  //and this will get the new title
  var newName = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString(); 
  if (newName != oldName)
  {
    using (var site = new SPSite("http://yoursitename"))
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
      var list = web.Lists["Tasks"];
      var items = list.Items.OfType<SPListItem>().Where(i => (string) i["Title"] == oldName);

      foreach (var item in items)
      {
        item["Title"] = newName;
        item.Update();
      }
    }
  }
base.ItemUpdating(properties);
}
```